# Problem fetching Smart Contract Results after issuance of SFT/NFT

Tags: api, multiversx

As mentioned in the documentation (https://docs.elrond.com/tokens/nft-tokens/#example-flow) we must be allowed to fetch to Token Identifier but the API (endpoint https://gateway.elrond.com/transaction/*txHash*?withResults=true) does not return the 'smartContractResults' anymore.

Previously it was perfectly working but it seems like some tiny things have changed in the documentation (https://docs.elrond.com/tokens/esdt-tokens/#parse-fungible-tokens-transfer-logs).

So my question is: How can we get the 'smartContractResults' informations? (the objective is to get the nonce of the created SFT/NFT)

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the Elrond Team can be find on the following GitHub issue:

https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/api.elrond.com/issues/870

To resume:

There is a temporary issue on the devnet gateway.
But the requested informations can be found with the following API endpoint:

https://devnet-api.elrond.com/transactions/:txHash